# how to auto-show tooltip on dropdown then hide when an item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Apologies for the dumb question in advance, I don't do much UI work so I'm unfamiliar with getting kendo  to do what I want. Basically I have a dropdown that sits inside a div. I want to attach a tooltip to it that will display when the page loads to draw the user's attention to it immediately. Then when the user selects something from the drop down, hide it. I was able to get it to display when you mouse over the dropdown itself but that's as far as I could get. Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#divMain").kendoTooltip({
            content: "<b>Tooltip here for drop-down</b>",
            width: 300,
            height: 50         
        });           
    });
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with JQuery
Say you have a dropdown with a class called `dropdown-content`, `<a>` tags for the href, a tooltip with an id `id="tooltip"` use the JQuery `css()` function and set it to `display:none` when your `dropdown-contents a tag has been clicked.

```js
$('.dropdown-content a').click(function() {
    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#tooltip {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Button with tooltip</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<span id="tooltip">This is a tooltip</span>
```

```
$('.dropdown-content a').click(function() {
    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is using the Kendo UI .NET Core version and it doesn't seem to work as it seems like this should. I did find another solution that doesn't require tooltips though so I'm going to go with that for now, thx